# using C# background worker calling a "toaster" popup not working

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, popup, backgroundworker

I'm quite new to C#, and I am working on a WPF application that has a background process that long poles a web service.
when I get certain codes back from the web service I will kick off methods.  I have all working but the one to create a "toaster" popup message.
I created a form to act as a toaster popup.  My problem is that it is being called from a backroundWorker thread, and it only executes once and it does not slide up the screen.  The timer function to raise up the screen does not run.  For simplicity I was using code from a previous question answered:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer timer;
    private int startPosX;
    private int startPosY;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // We want our window to be the top most
        TopMost = true;
        // Pop doesn't need to be shown in task bar
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        // Create and run timer for animation
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 50;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Move window out of screen
        startPosX = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width;
        startPosY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        SetDesktopLocation(startPosX, startPosY);
        base.OnLoad(e);
        // Begin animation
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Lift window by 5 pixels
        startPosY -= 5; 
        //If window is fully visible stop the timer
        if (startPosY < Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Height)
            timer.Stop();
        else
           SetDesktopLocation(startPosX, startPosY);
    }
}
```

Then in my bgWorker_DoWork  method I have:

```
    var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,
object>>(responseFromServer);
int notifyType = (int)dict["notificationType"];
switch (notifyType)
{ 
   case 6:
         Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer);  Form1 popup = new Form1();
         popup.Show();
         break; 
    default:
         Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
         break; 
}
```

Being new to C# I do not know how to keep the timer methods executing till the toaster message is fully displayed.

Or is there a better way to implement this toast popup then a form?

Help, please??
Thank you.

Comment: Where do you wire up the backgroundworker and call it?

Comment: @Blam in the MainWindow right after InitializeComponet();  I call setup_bgWorker(); and that runs 
_worker = new BackgroundWorker();
_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
_worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
_worker.RunWorkerAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rely on this working since it is using a different thread.
You need to dispatch the creation of the popup onto the main UI Thread

Sorry misread the Question and postet Winforms solution. Updated!

Use Control.Invoke

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       /* this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            var form2 = new Form2();
                            form2.Show();
                        }));  Winforms Method*/
         Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            var form2 = new Form2();
                            form2.Show();
                        }));

    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

You can in fact create windows on seperate threads. There are loads of tutorials on the web on how to do this. But remember that controls can only be accessed on the thread they are created on.